# Optimal row size to fetch at a time from a big table

Tags: sql, database, query-optimization, sybase

I have a very big table contains around 20 million rows. I have to fetch some 4 million rows from this table based on some filtering criteria. 
All the columns in filtering criteria are covered by some index and table stats are upto date.

I have been suggested that instead of loading all rows in a single go, use a batch size e.g. say 80000 rows at a time and that will be faster compared to loading all the rows at a time.

Can you suggest if this idea makes sense?

If it makes sense, what will be optimal row size to load at a time.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the selected rows?

Comment: I have to load these db rows in memory and maintain some in memory cache kind of stuff

Comment: Well, other than using an `order by` clause (which can have a significant impact on the performance of the query), I'm not sure how you'll be able to guarantee that a row won't show up in more than one batch.

Comment: He could pull a range of PKs if available.

Comment: ya right.... I am pulling a range of PK in each batch.

Comment: Fair enough.  In that case, my best advice would be to do some benchmarking.  There are too many things that can influence the optimal batch size--eg network speed (if the rows are being pulled out of the database to be processed outside of the database), hardware on the machine(s) running the database, all of the fiddly Dark Magic database configuration settings, etc--for there to be an "obvious" optimal number of rows per batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It can be much faster than single sql.
2. Split data using PK.
3. Batch size. It depends on the length of lines and processing time. Start with 10 000.
4. Thread  job if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSIS to manipulate your data...it does everything you are wanting like threading and optimizations on load sizing and cache.

Spin up a cube or look into Business Intelligence Data Warehouse Tools...